# try to obtain the hash key on MAC for integrating facebook in my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, macos

If someone has ever done this-obtained the hash key using the key tool on MAC please tell how u did it cause I'm pulling my hair out here.

Here is what I did:

First I found out that I should type these comands:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64
```

in my terminal in oder to get the `hash key`.

So I start typing:

```
 keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

As I pressed `ENTER` it asked for a password!

I gave up  this and try to set a password to my `keystore` by doing this:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

It asked for a password and the re-type password-All good until here.

The terminal also displayed this message:

```
[Storing my-release-key.keystore]
```

but it didn't tell where the keystore will be stored!!!

Now, I got the password and then tried again this magic command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`

It asked me for the password...I entered that and then it gave me this lovely little message thet drives me insane:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

So please if u know how could I obtain that key give me some details and I will appreciate it FOREVER.

Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You generated a second keystore with your selected password, you did not change the password on the `debug.keystore`. AFAIK, the default password for the debug-keystore is `android`.

Comment: Yes, when you locate it and substitute that path for `~/.android/debug.keystore` it should work.